# Is it possible to force GCC to output the exact bitwise instructions I give it without inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, gcc6

I've written code which looks like this:

```
char* xor_and_print(byte arr[], size_t buffSize, byte key)
{
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < buffSize; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", (arr[i] & ~key) | (key & ~arr[i]));
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

This is an xor operation blown up into more instructions. I am using gcc-6.3.0. Even when I compile with `-O0` flag, gcc turns this into one single `xor` instruction in the disassembly. Is it possible to coerce it into writing those specific asm instructions with a flag or must I use inline assembly language?

Comment: There is no general way to have any piece of non-asm C output a specific sequence of assembly instructions, no.

Comment: Declaring either `arr` or `key` as `volatile` makes it emit a lot more instructions. It depends on what exactly you want. E.g. it seems silly to force a `not key` every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `volatile` should avoid this optimization:

```
for(i = 0; i < buffSize; i++)
{
    byte volatile b = arr[i];
    printf("%c", (b & ~key) | (key & ~b));
}
```

But it will stay unoptimized for higher optimization levels too.